# Reformat Time response similar to db format

Tags: php

I have an API response that returns time in the below format

> "Time": "2019-04-26T08:44:22.283Z"

I tried to reformat it to insert it to my db in the below line of code

`$time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime(date($response->Time)));`

but its saving in the db as **1970-01-01 02:00:00**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pass it with strtotime,

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2019-04-26T08:44:22.283Z"));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/sjDAm)

Answer (score 0):

You could use use DateTime class to handle it correctly.

```
echo (new DateTime("2019-04-26T08:44:22.283Z"))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "\n";
```

https://3v4l.org/DEMrc